# Python: Best practice to report an error during closing a resource

Tags: python, contextmanager

What is the best practice in Python for reporting an error which occurs when closing a resource?

In particular, if I implement `__enter__` and `__exit__`, I can use

```
with my_library.connect(endpoint) as connection:
   connection.store_data("...")
```

But what should I do if closing my connection and persisting the changes fails, e.g. due to a network outage? I know that I could technically raise an error from within `__exit__` but is this best practice/idiomatic in Python? Or should I, e.g., provide a separate `persistChanges` method, let the `__exit__` swallow all errors, and then write in the documentation "if you don't call `persistChanges` you might lose your changes in error cases"?

My specific use case is: I am providing a Python API to other developers, and I wonder how to handle this case of "error on closing the resource" such that my API follows Python best practices/meets the expectations of Python devs using my library.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making a custom error/warning class for your library. this can be very, very simple. There already exists a set of [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) that you can extend from. Based on your description above, I would recommend extending the [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) like this:

```py
class MyLibraryConnectionError(RuntimeError):
    pass
```

or, if you want to only throw a warning, using the [`ResourceWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ResourceWarning) like this:

```py
class MyLibraryConnectionWarning(ResourceWarning):
    pass
```

There is also the [`RuntimeWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeWarning) that could be extended for similar effect.

If you feel that `ResourceWarning`, `RuntimeWarning`, and `RuntimeError` don't accurately describe the exception, you can also just have them inherit directly from `Exception` or `Warning`, depending on whether you want them to only be flagged in Developer mode(Warning), or if you want the full exception functionality.

You can throw these like any other exception:

```py
throw MyLibraryConnectionError("The underlying resource failed to close")
throw MyLibraryConnectionWarning("The underlying resource failed to close")
```

or even catch your dependency's thrown exception:

```py
def __exit__(...):
    try:
        # potentially dangerous code with connections
        underlyingConnection.close()
    except TheErrorYouSeeThrown as e: # you can probably make this Exception instead of TheErrorYouSeeThrown. The more specific the better, so you don't accidentally catch random errors you didn't mean to.
        throw MyLibraryConnectionError(e.message) # or whatever this needs to be, depending on the thrown exception type
```

Then your users could implement like so:

```py
try:
    with my_library.connect(endpoint) as connection:
        connection.store_data("...")
except my_library.MyLibraryConnectionError as e:
    # handle appropriately, or ignore
except Exception as e:
    # Handle other errors that happen, that your library doesn't cause.
```

Comment: @Vogelsgesang, if this answer solved your problem, please accept this as your solution